# What is a more efficient way to find matches of strings in a NumPy array as substrings in another array?

Tags: python, numpy, performance

I've got two NumPy arrays containing strings. I want to use each string in the first array to search in the second array if this string is contained as a substring there.

As a very easy example:

```
import numpy as np

result_list = []
array_1 = np.array(['ab', 'fo', 'ba'])
array_2 = np.array(['lab', 'abc', 'zwf', 'foo', 'bar'])

for word_to_search in array_1:
    for potential_word in array_2:
        if word_to_search in potential_word:
            result_list.append(potential_word)

# delete duplicates
result_list = list(set(result_list))

# result_list = ['lab', 'abc', 'foo', 'bar']
```

I tried it with basic Python lists and also with NumPy arrays. The latter are much better due to performance reasons but I still think that there must be a better solution.

As my `array_1` has about 11,000,000 entries and my `array_2` has about 300,000 entries I need to have a very performant approach, which is not the case for my current solution.

Comment: `numpy doesn't do anything special with strings. Lists will be beter for this.

Comment: What do you mean by performance reasons?  Did you do time tests?  or are you just assuming `numpy` is faster based on some sort of 'reputation'?

Answer (score 0):

After the step `result.append(potential_word)` you can break out of that for loop, in this way you will have no duplicates and will definitely save time. Also you need to change the order of the loops for that, outer loop loops through `array_2` and the inner through `array_1`.

```
import numpy as np

result_list = []
array_1 = np.array(['ab', 'fo', 'ba'])
array_2 = np.array(['lab', 'abc', 'zwf', 'foo', 'bar'])

for potential_word in array_2:
    for word_to_search in array_1:
        if word_to_search in potential_word:
            result_list.append(potential_word)
            break

print(result_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can employ the existing short-circuit methods `any` and `all`; here, you need only `any`.

```
result_list = [word for word in array_2
               if any(digram in word for digram in array_1)]
```

Result:

```
['lab', 'abc', 'foo', 'bar']
```

You could also use `filter`:

```
result_list = list(filter(lambda word: 
                           any(digram in word for digram in array_1), 
                       array_2)
```

Comment: Those are some interesting suggestions! Could you elaborate a bit how they work?

Comment: Please look up `any`, `filter`, `lambda`, and list comprehensions.  Then post what you still don't understand.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  Once you've covered the [expected research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), I'll be happy to fill in any gaps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a slick trick to make it much faster, but I have some slight improvement to offer. Using `numpy.arrays` has no effect in this case because you're manually looping over the single entries anyways. The arrays might only offer an advantage if there are some numpy methods that can help us with your task. For now I would suggest removing entries from `list_2` once they were matched and using a `while` loop to check if `list_2` still has items.

**EDIT**

Using `set` logic right from the beginning actually seems even a bit faster. I've added the method.

Here are some rudimentary speed comparisons and included [@Prune's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66753839/5472354) suggestions as well:

```
from time import time


def original(list_1, list_2, result_list):
    for word_to_search in list_1:
        for potential_word in list_2:
            if word_to_search in potential_word:
                result_list.append(potential_word)
    return list(set(result_list))


def while_loop(list_1, list_2, result_list):
    i = 0
    while i < len(list_1) and list_2:
        word_to_search = list_1[i]
        for potential_word in list_2:
            if word_to_search in potential_word:
                result_list.append(potential_word)
                list_2.remove(potential_word)
        i += 1

    return result_list


def set_(list_1, list_2, result_list):
    result_set = set()
    for word_to_search in list_1:
        for potential_word in list_2:
            if word_to_search in potential_word:
                result_set.add(potential_word)
    return list(result_set)


def any_(list_1, list_2, result_list):
    return [
        word for word in list_2 if any(digram in word for digram in list_1)
    ]


def filter_(list_1, list_2, result_list):
    return list(
        filter(lambda word: any(digram in word for digram in list_1), list_2)
    )


methods = {
    'original': original,
    'while_loop': while_loop,
    'any': any_,
    'filter': filter_,
}

result_list = []
list_1 = ['ab', 'fo', 'ba']
list_2 = ['lab', 'abc', 'zwf', 'foo', 'bar']
for name, method in methods.items():
    start = time()
    for i in range(10000):
        method(list_1, list_2, result_list)
    stop = time()
    print(f'{name}: {stop-start}')
```

Returns:

```
original: 1.475600004196167
while_loop: 0.006448030471801758
set: 0.004959821701049805
any: 0.006943941116333008
filter: 0.008928060531616211
```

Depending on your actual data this may be completely off though.

**EDIT**

I feel like there may be some nifty way to use `list_2.__str__()` and some string methods, which would be very fast, but I just can't think of one at the moment. You could also use `regex`, but that would probably be way to slow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @mapf, 
my problem is that in 99% the list_1 elements are not part of list_2. 
that's why the removing entries from list_2 when a match is done, is not really making a difference. 

By using __str__() I'm 3x faster. So thanks for that. 
Maybe I find another way how I can improve it even further.